# How to add text values to a subplot?

Tags: matlab

'Morning all,
I've read everything i can find and for some reason i'm still struggling with the syntax.
I'm calling a function from my GUI which plots into 4 subplots. My issue is adding text to the subplots, I'm getting no errors but the text is not showing...
The function for the main screen of the GUI:

```
function Main(varargin)
ColorMap = cool(100);
BackgroundColor = ColorMap(50,:);
figure('Units','Normalized',...
    'Position',[.06 .12 .88 .75],...
    'Color',BackgroundColor,'NumberTitle','Off',...
    'Menubar','None','Name','Rod Inputs')
m1 = uimenu('label','File');
m2 = uimenu('label','Bending & Shear');
uimenu(m1,'Label','CHS Inputs','Callback',@CHS);
uimenu(m2,'Label','Bending','Callback',@CantileverUDL);
uimenu(m1,'Label','Exit','Callback',@Quit);
```

The function for the calculator:

```
function [M,V,dydx,y] = CantileverUDL(varargin)
%% Cantilever with UDL
% Suggested values:
% w = 300;
% EI = 60e6;
% L = 4;
input = inputdlg({'Length(m) = ',...
    'w(N/m2) = ',...
    'Flexural Stiffness(EI) = '});
n = str2double(input{1});
w = str2double(input{2});
EI = str2double(input{3});
L = (0:1/n:n)';
dydx = w.*L.^3/(6*EI);
y = -w.*L.^4/(8*EI);
M = w.*L.^2/2;
V = w.*L;
[maxdydx, idydx] = max(dydx);
[maxy, iy] = max(-y);
[maxM, iM] = max(M);
[maxV, iV] = max(-V);
figure(1)
clf
hold on
grid on
sp1 = subplot(4,1,1)
plot(L,dydx,'r')
title('Slope')
t1 = text(idydx,maxdydx,['max slope = ', maxdydx],'Parent',sp1,'Units','Normalized');
set(t1,'HorizontalAlignment','center');
sp2 = subplot(4,1,2)
plot(L,y,'b')
title('Deflection')
sp3 = subplot(4,1,3)
plot(L,M,'k')
title('Bending moment')
sp4 = subplot(4,1,4)
area(L,V)
title('Shear force')
end
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? It's a really frustrating problem for me which i can't seem to solve....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
t1 = text(L(idydx),maxdydx,['max slope = ', maxdydx],'Parent',sp1);
```

instead of

```
t1 = text(idydx,maxdydx,['max slope = ', maxdydx],'Parent',sp1,'Units','Normalized');
```

There are two issues in your code:

1. You are using the index instead of the x value to position your text
2. You are using normalized units but you are not normalizing your x and y values

Comment: Can't believe I missed that...Your solution works well, thanks very much!